# What bracha would the fruit of a parasitic plant be? (Or the plant itself.)

Tags: halacha, blessing, agriculture

Parasitic plants do not grow in the ground, instead they grow on other plants. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_plant

List of examples: http://www.parasiticplants.siu.edu/ParasiteFood.html

So would it be like a mushroom which does not grow from the ground? Or would it be like a plant because A: It uses photosynthesis, and B: It grows on a living plant, which in turn grows on the ground?

Not all parasitic plants use photosynthesis, but they do grow on a plant that uses it, does that change the answer?

Also, what bracha is the plant itself, not just the fruit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [Eruvin 28b](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=491) talks about this very topic!

From what I could see the proper bracha is Ha'adama since if the source plant (which does grow from the ground) is cut the parasitic plant dies too.